# How to get ref in DOM node's children in React?

Tags: reactjs

**The question is:**

**How to get ref (as ReactElement not DOM), in a node with prop ref.**

**Example below**

Have a class MyTable rendered as:

```
 <table ref="myTable">
     {this.state.list.map(name=>
         <AddVarTableRow key={name} myName={name}/>
     )}
 </table>
```

And in componentDidUpdate, wanna do this:

```
React.Children.forEach(this.refs.tbody.props.children, (item,idx)=>{
   item.setState(...)
});
```

But got a warn:

> Warning: ReactDOMComponent: Do not access .props of a DOM node; instead, recreate the props as `render` did originally or read the DOM properties/attributes directly from this node (e.g., this.refs.box.className).

So I changed to:

```
React.Children.forEach(this.refs.tbody.children, (item,idx)=>{
   item.setState(...)
});
```

And got:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object HTMLCollection]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

So.... anyway to do that?

Comment: You never set a component's state from another component. A component is in charge of its own state, no one else. You really need to tell us what you're trying to solve. This strikes me as a classic XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Thanks David. Actually,  I have a <table> which have dynamic children (<AddVarTableRow>). And after rendering, I want load data by AJAX and update the <table>'s children. So the question is React.Children.forEach is neither work on this.refs.myTable.children nor ..myTable.props.children(warning).

Answer (score 1):

In React, you don't actually have setters, at least not in the traditional object-orientated way. A React component can set its own state, but not any others.

The way a component updates its child components is by re-rendering them. A child's `props` are received from the parent component, so if the `props` need to change, the parent component simply re-renders them with a new set of props.

Your render function might look like this:

```
render: function () {
  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {this.state.data.map(function (user) {
          return (
            <Row
              firstName={user.firstName}
              lastName={user.lastName}
              age={user.age}
            />
          );
        })}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
}
```

Where the Row component looks like this:

```
var Row = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.firstName}</td>
        <td>{this.props.lastName}</td>
        <td>{this.props.age}</td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

Note that `render()` is called every time the state changes. So if you need to update the table with a new set of data, simply invoke `this.setState()` in the parent component, i.e.

```
this.setState({
  data: newData
});
```

And voila, table re-renders with the latest data.